# How can I select a subset of properties from a discriminated union and get proper type safety?

Tags: typescript

I'm building out some filtering UI for a reporting tool in React but I can't get the types quite right. Different field types (`'string'` or `'number'`) will have different filter modifiers that are allowed. Obviously strings won't be comparable by greater than or less than, but numbers will. In service of that, I've created a discriminated union with `fieldType` as the discriminant:

```
type Mod1 = 'eql' | 'neql' | 'contains' | 'notcontains';
type Mod2 = 'gt' | 'lt' | 'gte' | 'lte' | 'eql' | 'neql'

interface FilterCommon {
    fieldType: string,
    fieldName: string,
    selectedValues: string[]
}

interface StringFilter extends FilterCommon {
  fieldType: 'string',
  availableModifiers: Mod1[]
  selectedModifier: Mod1
}

interface NumberFilter extends FilterCommon {
  fieldType: 'number',
  availableModifiers: Mod2[]
  selectedModifier: Mod2
}
```

It's working great.

The issues come when I start working on the next layer above individual filters, i.e. filter sets. Users need to be able to combine multiple filters (i.e. less than and greater than to achieve a range). Like Filters, FilterSet will have a fieldType, list of available modifiers, and fieldname. Since FilterSet is representing a group of Filters, it will not directly have selectedModifier or selectedValues, and instead, those will be plucked off and used to create an array of data that can be used to construct string or number filters:

```
type DistributivePick<T, K extends keyof T> = T extends any
    ? Pick<T, K>
    : never;

type Filter = StringFilter | NumberFilter;

type FilterSet = DistributivePick<Filter, 'fieldType' | 'fieldName' | 'availableModifiers' > & {
    filters: Pick<Filter, 'selectedModifier' | 'selectedValues'>[]
}
```

Now this is where I've run into trouble. Since I've "picked" those fields *without* the discriminant, `selectedModifier` has now lost proper type support and it's just the union of `Mod1` and `Mod2` (`'gt' | 'lt' | 'gte' | 'lte' | 'eql' | 'neql' | 'eql' | 'neql' | 'contains' | 'notcontains'`). I'd rather *not* have to include the discriminant in each of those array items as it's redundant since the `fieldType` applies to the entire FilterSet.

I've come close to a solution using `Extract` and a `Discriminate` type:

```
type Discriminate<TUnion, TDiscriminantKey extends PropertyKey, TDiscriminantValue> = Extract<TUnion, Record<TDiscriminantKey, TDiscriminantValue>>
```

but I can't seem to get over the hump here. I'm searched around examples, and documentation and haven't found much to push me any closer. I'm not sure if I'm searching for the wrong thing, or if this is something that simply isn't achievable (seems like it should be).

I think I could probably solve this by making the underlying Filters and FilterSet use generics, but I think I'd prefer just having the component props drive the typing with the discriminated union.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction or let me know if I'm going at this in the wrong way so I can reset and come up with a different approach.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwIxQLxQOQQI4BsNQA+mAdjvkZgMZwnACGAliQM4HEYlzA11OsYA3AFgAUKEixEAJjSYA5sHaZcSyhkURlGVVvXltZPBjFjmwCACcAZvSrQAYo12WAwnAC2H2lADeYqECoa0YIXAQAFXAIAC4oFmBLZnkAGgCgkLCEADl6D1j4xOS00SD4sIgqCwQANXpcAFcIFjiEpJJ5AG0AXTEAX1NRcytbeygAZSKOpxcoCAAPCxIEFigZizdPbxI-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)

Thanks

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wXkZ9W) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] your example to show a failing use case. Let me know.

Comment: This seems to solve it; many thanks. I'll have to spend a bit of time with that code to understand exactly what's going on, but more than happy to accept that as an answer if/when you'd like to write it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining `FilterSet` the way you have, the [distribution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) over the `Filter` [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) only happens inside `DistributivePick<...>`; then when you [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) that with another type mentioning `Filter` separately, you've essentially said that each side of the intersection is independent of the other.  So it shouldn't be surprising that you end up accepting "cross-correlated" members.

What you want to do instead is represent the operation necessary to calculate `FilterSet` for each member of the `Filter` union separately, and then distribute that operation over the `Filter` union.  If you had an individual filter type named `F`, then that operation looks like `Pick<F, 'fieldType' | ...> & {filters: Pick<F, ...>[]}`.  Meaning the intersection needs to occur inside the distributive part and not outside of it.

To distribute over `Filter` with distributive conditional types, we need to take `Filter` and assign it to a type parameter `F`, and then check `F` with a conditional type.  (Distributive conditional types only happen when the checked type is a type parameter).  So here's one way to do it:

```
type FilterSet = Filter extends infer F ? F extends Filter ?
    Pick<F, 'fieldType' | 'fieldName' | 'availableModifiers'> & 
    { filters: Pick<F, 'selectedModifier' | 'selectedValues'>[] }
    : never : never
```

The assigning to `F` is being done with [conditional type inference using `infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types).  You could also have done this in multiple steps like this:

```
type FilterSetFor<F> = F extends Filter ?
    Pick<F, 'fieldType' | 'fieldName' | 'availableModifiers'> &
    { filters: Pick<F, 'selectedModifier' | 'selectedValues'>[] }
    : never
type FilterSet = FilterSetFor<Filter>;
```

Anyway, you can verify that this behaves how you want:

```
/*
type FilterSet = (Pick<StringFilter, "fieldType" | "fieldName" | "availableModifiers"> & {
    filters: Pick<StringFilter, "selectedModifier" | "selectedValues">[];
}) | (Pick<NumberFilter, "fieldType" | "fieldName" | "availableModifiers"> & {
    filters: Pick<NumberFilter, "selectedModifier" | "selectedValues">[];
}) */
```

Or, if that's not obvious enough, you can use a little utility type `Expand`

```
type Expand<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Expand<T[K]> } | never
```

to prompt the compiler to eagerly evaluate the type instead of leaving it represented in terms of `Pick` and intersections:

```
type ExpandedFilterSet = Expand<FilterSet>;
/* type ExpandedFilterSet = {
    fieldType: 'string';
    fieldName: string;
    availableModifiers: Mod1[];
    filters: {
        selectedModifier: Mod1;
        selectedValues: string[];
    }[];
} | {
    fieldType: 'number';
    fieldName: string; 
    availableModifiers: Mod2[];
    filters: {
        selectedModifier: Mod2;
        selectedValues: string[];
    }[];
} */
```

That's what you want.  And you can verify that it works:

```
const a: FilterSet = { // error!
    availableModifiers: ['eql'],
    fieldName: 'Fruits',
    fieldType: 'string',
    filters: [
        {
            selectedModifier: 'gt',
            selectedValues: ['apple', 'banana', 'cantalope']
        }
    ]
}; // Types of property 'selectedModifier' are incompatible
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwIxQLxQOQQI4BsNQA+mAdjvkZgMZwnACGAliQM4HEYlzA11OsYA3AChQkWIgBMaTAHNg7TLgWUM8iIozKNq8prJ4Mw4c2AQATgDN6VaADFG28wGE4AWze0oAb2EBIS0YIXAQAFXAIAC4oFmBzZlkAGn9A4IQAOXo3KJi4hOS-FmCIKjMEADV6XABXCBZo2PiSWQBtAF1hAF9jUwtrWygAZTzmhycoCAAPMxIEFigxsxd3TxIfFKCQ8MhojEaEjAL6ADcmXHoAI1wIeARGVPN6iWR2-yLr0ogEW-ug82jbkguj06H0bNB0tU3BcLIsLBNphBZvM4csPF5fAFNmEIrsSFCYeZDv4TmdLtcfg8nrdJK9CsVPt9EL8LACpMCxPZHEsZMMmrJUZRIdDYdyLCJRBEFmLzIMIMAZIKpjM5lBmJZ4XYoAB+BYIlUomU6-wABUYVAA1gAeOyJTCpLYRTQOjJZHQcUmOck3ZlUjAAPigADIfFBAk4nmbLTa7XsGWVKX9NO8SmVKjU6gH2lBun5omRjvD8xBC+ZjAB6ABUkvEqLlCvQAAoo9a+QlUXaAEQu7YQTuUbvYzLZfvETue85XH13KmdwMhzHhpaR82tkYCmVdlOMxMWUdQTvbtNVWosOftESdACUlGbq6twsJHYPPYi+8HaWHfYHE+9u8ec7BusWIRtELYPgSopOFu8ZfP+75Hl86anuebSXjelblsYJBuiwYDglAADywAABYWAA6vQIDAZy0pOPWdhwOYNqBugWrKkiqqCtq-h+OBtr2tivbOkObqaL+U7-mw868d4YYyiu0YCXGHwJr6SaqIhFQnpm-rZrmeZQAWFjGH4tF1vKioygxTE2jK-oiH4VZQOZ1mWU24FtqMm4vkJb4Di6X7vhJFLqRYZ7zsBS7hWB95eRu0EHlp8EDlpyF1Kh6G3uBj5QUsXavpA76BW6wWnF6klhQBkWLgpsXRrl5jPoesFMjOfwIa16URReXQYVhwI1tAACikz4bMVqhKxoYtAA0mqawWhAIBwJYUChG00SjeNCCTXNbSBp0lDGWWQ1QNt9CzF8FkNudY2XbtN0OcIzm0RdV0IDdMi1Wkva7PszRCBsn5ug066OSF04so8bIvGhGygcB9KqXBVWw0gjnI6mSE6U8AOtPDfidL1R3ED9jo7KQkFEo5JXZGD-KCFAJLlZOoXtTFzy0oT0Uw0jyVo1zmNpbjDMJL1RMk1AmHGMYvCxFA9DRF96CYpDUnRC0WCGG0BR0zkGB2OY1SMMAbB635lN7OuxIgcumuybxWM7oLagKAUfjO8eGZPFr9BgGA1yHJgFyXWHwcYFQl0MLgcCQBgHSe7mHSdEz5blhM5jmExACE60RPMq1QGA2eQOYoCYALHNEor5jQMwNBuPhwCMFOwhAA)